# Getting text between two comma in a paragraph sending only word

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0

Assume that I have a text like between.

```
string str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec at eros sit amet turpis viverra convallis sit amet in elit. Aenean imperdiet semper pretium. ellentesque vel fringilla neque. Morbi placerat varius dapibus.     Phasellus tincidunt ullamcorper orci, nec suscipit velit. Suspendisse tincidunt, magna at auctor tincidunt, velit dolor molestie augue, ac pulvinar nibh metus ac turpis. Sed adipiscing ultrices enim, sit amet volutpat nunc posuere in.Ut tempus rutrum quam, et consectetur risus. Maecenas vitae adipiscing turpis, ac bibendum dui.    Quisque adipiscing leo luctus quam scelerisque tristique. Donec volutpat vulputate vehicula. Vivamus a sapien vitae nisi blandit viverra. Nam magna lorem, faucibus a nulla ac, adipiscing tincidunt nisi. Quisque pellentesque ligula sit amet sollicitudin placerat.    In pretium condimentum sem, ac varius tortor vulputate in.    Quisque ac dictum orci. Sed magna nisi, aliquet non risus vel, molestie varius metus. In consectetur mauris erat, sed euismod dui ultricies eget. Curabitur eget urna non neque volutpat volutpat. Mauris cursus sodales nibh, vel dignissim enim bibendum rhoncus. Cras in arcu laoreet, rutrum metus nec, molestie quam. Phasellus congue, lorem mollis pulvinar fringilla, erat leo mattis purus, vel convallis massa mauris quis tortor. Pellentesque pretium arcu elit, ut consequat augue sollicitudin id. In eget tellus dictum, molestie neque nec, ultricies velit. Cras aliquet faucibus eros, semper pretium odio aliquet eu. Mauris accumsan vestibulum nisl id fringilla. Suspendisse potenti. In ac blandit diam. Quisque mollis elementum lacus, faucibus mattis erat. Phasellus interdum pulvinar mauris ut aliquet."
```

I have a word which is "odio" and I want to search it in above string statement.

> ... In eget tellus dictum, molestie neque nec, ultricies velit. Cras
>   aliquet faucibus eros, semper pretium **odio** aliquet eu. Mauris accumsan
>   vestibulum nisl id fringilla....

After I find it I get the index with IndexOf method like below:

```
var word = "odio";
var start = str.IndexOf(word);
```

I want to get sentence between two point includes odio.
Demanded result is:

> ... In eget tellus dictum, molestie neque nec, ultricies velit. **Cras
>   aliquet faucibus eros, semper pretium odio aliquet eu.** Mauris accumsan
>   vestibulum nisl id fringilla....

That is to say, how can I get the bold sentence only sending word which is odio at example?

Are there any way?

Comment: It is not a homework. But you looks like a teacher :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using `Split` would be easier:

```
var foundSentence = str.Split('.').Where(sentence=> sentence.Contains("odio")).First();
```

Comment: Hi, as you see I want to get "Cras aliquet faucibus eros, semper pretium odio aliquet eu." string. 
Your code works good but if there is "etc." I cannot take whole sentence isn't it? SHould I control another char ?